# My Makefile always builds all files

Tags: c, makefile, freebsd

This is running on FreeBSD which uses PMake instead of GMake.

This is my first Makefile. I used Google a lot to help create this as well as sources such as 'PMake — A Tutorial'. The only problem I can't solve is that every time I run the Makefile, it will compile every file even when there are no changes.

I have four directories. src for my source files, include for my headers, obj for the output and bin for the executable.

What I'm doing is scanning the source folder and creating a list of files to use for both the source and object as well as the headers. Typically I run 'make debug' for debugging and 'make myservice' otherwise.

If I run 'make clean', 'make debug', and 'make debug' it will clean my folders, make all files and then proceed to remake all files instead of doing nothing.

Based on my searching, I'm leaning towards the $(OBJ) rule being the problem, but I don't quite get that. In order for my target and debug rules to build they need to know how to build the objects.

```
CC  = clang

BINDIR = $(.CURDIR)/bin
OBJDIR = $(.CURDIR)/obj
SRCDIR = $(.CURDIR)/src
INCDIR = $(.CURDIR)/include

CFLAGS  = -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I$(INCDIR)
LFLAGS  = -lm -lpq -lpthread
LIBDIR  = -L/usr/local/lib

_SRC    != ls $(SRCDIR)/*.c
SRC = ${_SRC:T}
INC != ls $(INCDIR)/*.h
OBJ = ${SRC:S/src/obj/g:.c=.o}

TARGET = myservice

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(BINDIR)/$@ $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBDIR) $(LFLAGS)

debug: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -g -O0 -o $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET) $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBDIR) $(LFLAGS)

$(OBJ) : $(SRCDIR)/$(.PREFIX).c $(INCDIR)/$(.PREFIX).h
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*.o $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
```

**edit - New Makefile**

New Makefile. Doesn't rebuild if no changes. Has no debug, still issues figuring out debug.

```
CC      = clang

BINDIR = $(.CURDIR)/bin
OBJDIR = $(.CURDIR)/obj
SRCDIR = $(.CURDIR)/src
INCDIR = $(.CURDIR)/include

CFLAGS  = -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I$(INCDIR)
LFLAGS  = -lm -lpq -lpthread
LIBDIR  = -L/usr/local/lib

TARGET = $(BINDIR)/myservice

_SRC    != ls $(SRCDIR)/*.c
SRC     = ${_SRC:T}
INC     != ls $(INCDIR)/*.h
OBJ     = ${SRC:S/src/obj/g:.c=.o}

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBDIR) $(LFLAGS)

$(OBJ) : $(SRCDIR)/$(.PREFIX).c $(INCDIR)/$(.PREFIX).h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*.o $(TARGET)
```

**edit - Working Makefile**

Added if conditional for debugging purposes.

```
CC  = clang

BINDIR = $(.CURDIR)/bin
OBJDIR = $(.CURDIR)/obj
SRCDIR = $(.CURDIR)/src
INCDIR = $(.CURDIR)/include

CFLAGS  = -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I$(INCDIR)
.if make(debug)
CFLAGS += -g -O0
.endif
LFLAGS  = -lm -lpq -lpthread
LIBDIR  = -L/usr/local/lib

TARGET = $(BINDIR)/myservice

_SRC    != ls $(SRCDIR)/*.c
SRC = ${_SRC:T}
INC != ls $(INCDIR)/*.h
OBJ = ${SRC:S/src/obj/g:.c=.o}

all: $(TARGET)

debug: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBDIR) $(LFLAGS)

$(OBJ): $(SRCDIR)/$(.PREFIX).c $(INCDIR)/$(.PREFIX).h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*.o $(TARGET)
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip: CMake is a bit higher level and might sidestep some of this.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thank you for the tip. For now, I would like to continue with PMake so I can figure out where I am going wrong and learn from it. I took a quick look at CMake examples. It is definitely something I will look into further once I have learnt a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `make debug` cannot do nothing, `debug` is phony target, not an actual output file, at least the link phase will be re-run.

Furthermore, re-running the link phase with `-g -O0` would not recompile you source files with debug information and no optimizations.

Incidentally, the `$(TARGET)` rule is a phony rule too, it produces `$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)`, not `$(TARGET)`.

You should rewrite your makefile with different rules to make object and binary output files in different directories for debug and release modes.  `gmake` patterns make this easy to write, I don't know about `pmake` or `cmake` for this purpose.

Comment: With your help discussing PHONY targets, specifically my $(TARGET) rule and my $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET) rule, I was able to re-write my rules and get it working. I learned a bit about PHONY targets, but not enough. From my understanding, a PHONY rule will always run if told. So by making a debug rule and calling 'make debug', it will always build because debug will never exist. Is it possible to create a rule that enables debugging while not rebuilding unnecessary? I've edited my main post with the new Makefile.

Comment: You can make a debug rule that depends on the debug executable file and make a separate rule to make the debug executable from the debug object files and yet another generic rule to make the debug object files from the source files.  You should also list Makefile as a dependent for all these rules to force recompilation when you modify the Makefile, as you may have changed the commands and/or compilation options.

Comment: I believe I've found a way without creating new duplicate rules, but the conditionals don't seem to work. [Conditionals - PMake](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/pmake/book.html#condition). `#if defined(DEBUG) || make(debug) CFLAGS  += -g -O0 #endif` Using that code, regardless of what I run with make, it adds the -g -O0 flags. My guess was DEBUG was defined somehow, so I removed that to leave just `make(debug)`. Running `make` still adds the flags even though I'm not running `make debug`.

Comment: @quickblueblur: Not a good fix, because you do not keep track of whether the object modules have been compiled for the debug or the release version.  Why not use 2 separate directories for debug objects and release objects, or maybe use different extensions, such as .r.o and .d.o ?

Comment: The reason I don't want to do all that is it creates duplication. Wherein all modifications will require me to ensure I modify multiple rules so that they will always match. If I'm switching between to or from debug, I do a make clean anyway. So keeping it simple like this works for me. As for the issue, I figured it out with the [manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)). The manual uses `.` for the conditional instead of the `#` that the tutorial uses. Changing it up to match the manual works. I have edited question with the final solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In this case, test the environment variable DEBUG to change the compilation options in the Makefile and use the same target but invoke make this way: `DEBUG=1 make`